# How to split screen into 2 columns vertically and apply full page scroll?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]
I am having a bit of an issue with splitting the screen into 2 sections vertically then wrapping the whole page with a `SingleChildScrollView`. Without `ConstrainedBox` the columns won't be displayed, is there any other way of doing this?, Will there be any performace issues with using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height` for wrapping the both sections in a ConstrainedBox to expand to full screen's height?

```
body: RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: () async{
   print('testing');

},
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
    parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 
AppBar().preferredSize.height), //----------> I want to avoid using BoxConstraints
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, top: 24.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
          //  flex: 1,
            child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            // height: 20 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
                Container(
                // height: 100.0,
                // width: 100.0,
                  child: Text('teacher_photo_album_flow.listing_title'.tr(), 
style: CustomTextStyle.pageSectionTitle(context),),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
            
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Container(
                              height: 25 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            //  width: double.infinity,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                child: Image.network(this.photoAlbums1[0]['album_cover'],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 4,
                                  child: 
                                    Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Text(this.photoAlbums1[0]['title'], 
style: CustomTextStyle.titleOnelineEllipses(context),),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                //  flex: 1,
                                  child: 
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: Text(this.photoAlbums1[0]['newDate'], 
style: CustomTextStyle.silentTextDate(context),),
                                  )
                                ,),
                              ],
                            ),
                        ],),
                      )
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 3 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                    ),
            ],
            ),
            ),
          ),
        photoAlbums2.length > 0 ? Expanded(
          // flex: 2,
          child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [ 
              Expanded(
                // flex: 2,
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemCount: this.photoAlbums2.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i) {
            
                        return 
                        GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){

                        },
                        child: Container(

                          child: Column(children: [
                          Container(
                              height: 15 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                              //  width: double.infinity,
                                width: double.infinity,
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                child: Image.network(this.photoAlbums2[i]['album_cover'],
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 1.0 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(this.photoAlbums2[i]['title'], 
style: CustomTextStyle.titleOnelineEllipses(context),),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 0.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(this.photoAlbums2[i]['newDate'], 
style: CustomTextStyle.silentTextDate(context),),
                            ),
                          ],),
                        )
                      );
            
                      }
                      
                      ),
            ),]
          ),
          ),
        ) : SizedBox(height: 0,)
        ],),
                        ),
  ),
),
);
```

Comment: You like have `SingleChildScrollView` on body scrollable means top Box will be also move based on main body scroll?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yup that's correct, I want the whole page to scroll. So I have disabled the scroll on my GridView with `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`
My only problem is without `ConstrainedBox` specified height, the whole page won't be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `LayoutBuilder` to get screen size.

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () async {},
            child: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .3,// amount of height you want or the widget you like to include with `ConstrainedBox`
                ),
              ),
              SliverGrid.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    11,
                    (index) => Container(
                      color: index % 3 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.cyanAccent,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]));
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I am doing something similar with `ConstrainedBox` and passing the height and deducting the appBar's height `maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 
AppBar().preferredSize.height`

Was thinking if there are better ways to do this, instead of explicitly passing the height

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(''),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width : 10,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container( 
                
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                     child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            
            SizedBox(height : 10),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width : 10,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container( 
                
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                     child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
             SizedBox(height : 10),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width : 10,),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container( 
                
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                     child : Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
    )
```